# What does swift language version build setting in Xcode mean?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-construction, version

My framework project was upgraded to Swift 5 and Xcode 10.3 but now I still want to build it on Swift 4.2.

I tried to set `Swift Language Version` in build setting of `Xcode 10.3` to `Swift 4.2`. I wonder why it has some syntaxes that only appear on `Swift 5.0` but the project was built successfully but when I put that framework to project running on Xcode 10 (it was shipped with `Swift 4.2`) then it cannot be built. The error was 'SWIFT 5.0 NOT SUPPORTED...'.

So what `Swift Language Version` exactly means in this case? Do we have a way to build this framework with Swift 4.2 with Xcode 10.3? Thank everyone for any answer.

Comment: @Dai, Swift Language Version means which swift version your project supported and we can change this is Build setting if your Xcode supports that swift version.

Comment: Did you figured this out? the below answer does not seem to explain this really....

Comment: @benchuk I've read an explanation on stackoverflow but I couldn't find it for you for now. As I know when a Xcode version released it will be shipped with a swift complier version. Things that you configure in build setting just make it work with source code of older swift version and that's why your output framework has swift version not like in your build setting.

Comment: @DaiTran Thanks for the answer, in general it seems not to do what you have suggested, for example I am on xCode 12 (the toolchain version is swift 5)
my project works fine on xCode 10 with toolchain swift 4 (the code is written for swift 4) 
when selecting swift version 4 on the project settings the project does not compile on xcode 11 - the only thing that made it compile is changing the xCode 11 tool-chain to swift 4

Answer (score 2):

@Dai, Swift Language Version means which swift version your project supported and we can change this is in  Build setting if your Xcode supports that swift version.

- Go To Build setting
- Swift Compiler Language
- Then change the version which you project supported.

[image: This is screenshot of Xcode where you can change the swift version]

Comment: when does this mater? when should I choose a different version over the other?